# "imagejpeg" function is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, images, headers

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/city_81.jpg');

// choose a color for the ellipse
$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

// draw the white ellipse
imagefilledellipse($image, 500, 100, 6, 6, $ellipseColor);

// Output the image.
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

But when I try to run the same code within wordpress it doesn't work . It outputs some garbage value, and as well as warning

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\general-template.php:2752)

Comment: I have GD library installed and enabled 
and allow_url_fopen = on

Comment: make sure that there is no white spaces before the php opening tag "<?php" and after end tag "?>"

Comment: yeah it is checked

Comment: did u try using separate php file for header code like in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358484/adding-php-file-to-wordpress-header-already-sent

Comment: yeah tried , but didn't work

Comment: Well, you actually sent a `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`, so this is pretty much expected behavior. Don't send headers from the middle of your template. And please [edit] your question and show in which context you are including the code. Also: Add your "garbage value" - it might be important (as everything that comes with an error).